# How to enable scroll functionality in elastic search

Tags: python, elasticsearch, dsl

I have a web url api which serving by the elastic search.

- My web urls is https://data.emp.com/employees
- I have 50 employee(data) in my index
- On each scroll 7 employee will be adding take 7,14,21..49,50
- On each scroll 7 employee will appear first then 14 employees, ..49,50 employees
- My Api below URL is all 50 employees at one shot

```
    def elastic_search():
        """
         Return full search using match_all
        """
        try:
     
            full_search= es.search(index="employees",scroll = '2m',size = 10,body={ "query": {"match_all": {}}})
            hits_search = full_search['hits']['hits']
            return hits_search 
        except Exception as e:
            logger.exception("Error" + str(e))
            raise
```

I have modified above code like below

```
        sid =  search["_scroll_id"]
        scroll_size = search['hits']['total']
        scroll_size = scroll_size['value']
        # Start scrolling
        while (scroll_size > 0):

            #print("Scrolling...")
            page = es.scroll(scroll_id = sid, scroll = '1m')

            #print("Hits : ",len(page["hits"]["hits"]))
            
            # Update the scroll ID
            sid = page['_scroll_id']
        
            # Get the number of results that we returned in the last scroll
            scroll_size = len(page['hits']['hits'])
            search_text = page['hits']['hits']
            print (search_text)
```

My api is throwing `[]` because my last `search_text` giving blank.
In the log it is printing each set of 7 employees. But My web url api is loading loading and last it showing blank page

Please help in updating in returning "hits_search" which is in elastic_search function

Comment: i looked into url https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-and-scroll-in-python-953 couldnot understood much

Comment: so what's the problem, just set the size 7 and scroll = '7s' doesn't mean 7 docs

Comment: @AlwaysSunny, can you guide me writing query . my code giving 50 dcos at one shot. Anu url also would be helpful

Comment: BTW how many data points are there in the document? You don't need to scroll unless you need to paginate over very large dataset (>10k)

Comment: @SahilGupta sorry for the late reply only have just 50 data points

Comment: @Nons: then it doesn't make any sense to use scroll API. Simply search & paginate using search api.

Comment: @sahil gupta, can you guide or link also enough

Comment: @SahilGupta  if you meant to say like `        search = es.search(index="employees",body={"from" : 0, "size" : 7, "query": {"match_all": {}}})
        search_text = search['hits']['hits']
`  then its not working as I only got 7 documents only in api

Answer (score 2):

I guess elasticsearch [from and size](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-from-size.html) will do the trick for you if you have doc **less than ≤ 10k**. But still if you want to use the [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/scroll-api.html) API then this is what you need,

```
    # declare a filter query dict object
    match_all = {
        "size": 7,
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        }
    }

    # make a search() request to get all docs in the index
    resp = client.search(
        index = 'employees',
        body = match_all,
        scroll = '2s' # length of time to keep search context
    )
    
    # process the first 7 documents here from resp
    # iterate over the document hits for each 'scroll'
    for doc in resp['hits']['hits']:
        print ("\n", doc['_id'], doc['_source'])
        doc_count += 1
        print ("DOC COUNT:", doc_count)
    
    # keep track of pass scroll _id
    old_scroll_id = resp['_scroll_id']

    # use a 'while' iterator to loop over document 'hits'
    while len(resp['hits']['hits']):

        # make a request using the Scroll API
        resp = client.scroll(
            scroll_id = old_scroll_id,
            size = 7,
            scroll = '2s' # length of time to keep search context
        )

        # iterate over the document hits for each 'scroll'
        for doc in resp['hits']['hits']:
            print ("\n", doc['_id'], doc['_source'])
            doc_count += 1
            print ("DOC COUNT:", doc_count)
```

**See Ref:** https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-to-make-scroll-queries-to-get-all-documents-in-an-elasticsearch-index-752

Comment: see the reference link it will help you out

Comment: I have tried and update my new issue, can you check please